# Active window changes when clicking inside a window

Tags: macos, application-switcher

This is what happens:

1. I switch to an application (app 1) so it is active/in front.
2. When I click inside app 1, another app (app 2) gets focus. It's like I click through app 1.
3. To prevent app 2 to get focus every time I click inside app 1, I have to click on the "title bar" / "area where you can drag the window" of app 1.

This doesn't happen all the time, but too often. Running OSX 10.8.4 on a 2008 MBP. Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Is it happening when you use an application through the X11 window server? Or can you identify an application (1) when it occurs (for example Gimp) which triggers this behavior regularly?

Comment: @Gbugnard Does OSX use X11? I'd have to confirm this, but I think both Google Chrome and Adobe Bridge has this (app 1) behaviour.

Comment: X11 is not necessarily used for all applications. But some app coming from unix might (e.g. Gimp). The use of X11 can be sometimes confusing with the management of the pile of windows on screen and which application is running on the front. But it does not seem to be the case for your problem, since Chrome or Adobe Bridge do not use it.